# How can I synchronize users in a master-slave server setup on debian squeeze?

Tags: linux, replication, debian-squeeze, users, user-accounts

I'm currently setting up a 1:1 replication of a linux server. To simplify the process of updating users and groups I considered changing the uids and gids on the slave server to have them all like on the master server, so that if a new user is added on the master server I just have to copy passwd, groups etc. to the slave.

What I'm trying to do is to set up one slave server as a backup solution if the production server is offline for some reason. I wanted to synchronize only system users (everything inside /etc/passwd etc.) and no mail accounts or any other type of users.

Is it a good/common approach or should I better do it another way?

Comment: what kind of users? system (machine) users? nominal accounts for humans?

Comment: If you wanna do something like centralized authentication for your linux system users you should read about LDAP or FreeIPA. The way you are trying accomplish this task is imo wrong and it will be soon and administrating nightmare...

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish ?? You wanna have two servers in some kind of HA cluster??

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to set up one slave server as a backup solution if the production server is offline for some reason. I wanted to synchronize only system users (everything inside /etc/passwd etc.) and no mail accounts or any other type of users.

Answer (score 0):

Sychronizing **users** this way is a valid approach for a **very small** number of servers if you know about everything to synchronize.

However, I would use LDAP instead.